# can i sort element in css using attribute value?

Tags: html, css, image, sorting

I have a list of images, those image elements have a attribute like `index`, which I want to use to sort the element of the images in ascending order. with the help of CSS.

Because that index attribute value will change dynamically, more image will also be added by Ajax. So when it will update, that time it will be arranged in that order without doing anything.

```css
.img_container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

.img_container img {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x150/000000/ffffff&text=1" index="1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x150/000000/ffffff&text=10" index="10">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/110x150/000000/ffffff&text=11" index="11">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/140x150/000000/ffffff&text=14" index="14">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/ffffff&text=2" index="2">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/120x150/000000/ffffff&text=12" index="12">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/130x150/000000/ffffff&text=13" index="13">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000000/ffffff&text=3" index="3">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000000/ffffff&text=4" index="4">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000000/ffffff&text=15" index="15">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x150/000000/ffffff&text=5" index="5">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000000/ffffff&text=6" index="6">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x150/000000/ffffff&text=17" index="17">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000000/ffffff&text=7" index="7">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x150/000000/ffffff&text=16" index="16">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/ffffff&text=8" index="8">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/180x150/000000/ffffff&text=18" index="18">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/ffffff&text=9" index="9">
</div>
```

Let me know if there is any easy way to do this in CSS.

Comment: When the image elements come in with ajax, can you add other attributes instead of `"index"` ?

Comment: @JakeParis for what?, because from ajax it's just HTML which i append to `.img_container` div.

Comment: Because if you can add any attribute you want, instead of doing `index="3"`, you could do something like `style="grid-row: 3"` (with `display:grid` on the parent of course).

Comment: @JakeParis yes i can change parents element, but i can't change html which i get !

Comment: Is there a limit with the indexes?  Like will you expect index="1000000"?

Comment: @DanielGimenez There will only be around 200 images at most.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a good CSS-only solution yet without modifying the HTML or adding inline styles. In the future, it may be possible to achieve this using the [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function in CSS, but currently this doesn't have wide support for being able to use it outside of the `content` property.

If the more advanced usage is adopted, a future solution could look like this. **Note, this will not work in most current browsers.** And you should also use the `data-` prefix for custom attributes.

```css
.img_container {
  border: 2px black solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img_container img {
  margin: 5px;
  order: attr(data-index); /* will not work yet in most browsers */
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x150/000000/ffffff&text=1" data-index="1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x150/000000/ffffff&text=10" data-index="10">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/110x150/000000/ffffff&text=11" data-index="11">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/140x150/000000/ffffff&text=14" data-index="14">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/ffffff&text=2" data-index="2">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/120x150/000000/ffffff&text=12" data-index="12">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/130x150/000000/ffffff&text=13" data-index="13">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000000/ffffff&text=3" data-index="3">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000000/ffffff&text=4" data-index="4">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000000/ffffff&text=15" data-index="15">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x150/000000/ffffff&text=5" data-index="5">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x150/000000/ffffff&text=6" data-index="6">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x150/000000/ffffff&text=17" data-index="17">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x150/000000/ffffff&text=7" data-index="7">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/160x150/000000/ffffff&text=16" data-index="16">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/ffffff&text=8" data-index="8">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/180x150/000000/ffffff&text=18" data-index="18">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/ffffff&text=9" data-index="9">
</div>
```